# Licensing of Oracle Standard One multiple homes

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, license, standard-edition

we I have a server with Oracle SE One ... I need to separate the test data from prod data as each one has it's own schema, I will do 1 of 2 which is both are OK for the dev team:

1. Create a new instance and move the test into it
2. Install a new home and then create the new instance into it then move the data, I like this option because I can test the Oracle patch on the test home before applying it on the prod ...

any thought on the license?
we already have the license, but do we need additional one if we do both or any one them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.  Questions on licensing should be referred to the vendor, and an answer obtained in writing from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer for licensing questions is: contact your oracle sales representative.

With Oracle you license cpu's. If your test and prod run on the same cpu's, they don't need a new license. As long as it all runs on the same cpu's, it does not matter if you have multiple databases (and instances) or run it all in one single database. Normally we don't mix test and prod in the same database so at least make sure to create separate databases for test and prod.

If you run this on the same machine, it could be wise to run test using a test account and prod database using a prod account. This also requires 2 separate ORACLE_HOME's on that single machine but this does give you some control about the separation of your environments.

Comment: Separate homes is good for testing patches/upgrades before applying them to production too.

Comment: Thanks guys ... that what I needed to know, I'm all with doing it on a separate homes :-)